# PyCharm. Изменение цвета каретки в зависимости от языка ввода

Tags: pycharm, color

Было бы очень удобно определять язык ввода по цвету каретки.
Такие программки есть в интернете. Платные и бесплатные. Даже можно выбрать, чтобы флаг был возле каретки. Но все они не работают в Pycharm. Да и с другими приложениями у них тоже проблемы.
Планирую переходить на слепую печать. Так что необходимость данной функции станет ещё выше.

В настройках Pycharm можно менять цвет каретки(Settings - Editor - Colors & Fonts - General - Caret). А вот так, чтобы в зависимости от языка ввода - такого нет.

Напишу-ка я письмо в Jetbrains.
Как ответят - отпишусь.

Comment: А какая ОС у вас?

Comment: Windows 7______

Comment: Достаточно специфическое требование. Английский язык - стандарт де-факто в программировании. Это значит, что бОльшая часть текста будет написана именно на нем. Русский (или любой другой) язык может понадобится при редактировании ресурсов (переводов, к примеру), а это, как показывает практика, не столь частая процедура для разработчика

Comment: "Планирую переходить на слепую печать. Так что необходимость данной функции станет ещё выше." - вы с закрытыми глазами что ли печатать будете? Тогда зачем тогда цветом выделять, раз вы не увидите этого? Или вы считаете, что скорость набора увеличится настолько, что когда вы заметите что язык не тот уже будет набрана куча кода? Так если скорость будет такой, то вы быстро сможете это исправить. Не вижу ни одной причины, по которой может понадобиться этот функционал.

Comment: Ну вы загнули!Это было бы круто, если бы с закрытыми глазами :)
Слепая печать - печать при которой смотришь не на клавиатуру, а на экран.
Метод слепой печати или десятипальцевый метод.

Comment: @AntonKirienko, цвет/форма курсора/каретки — это такой же «костыль», как и индикатор раскладки. «костыль», вызванный использованием *циклического переключения раскладок*. сделайте переключение **не**циклическим — и надобность в «костылях» отпадёт сама собой. // я подразумеваю механизм **в**ключения нужной раскладки при нажатии уникального для каждой раскладки сочетания клавиш (в идеале ­— не сочетания, а по одной клавише на одну раскладку, но где ж их столько взять свободных на клавиатуре?).

Comment: Поддерживаю просьбу - при написании комментариев к коду необходимо отслеживать режим раскладки. Естественно это нужно исключительно для новичков. Профи спокойно продолжат кодить в блокноте.